# Update value of global var

Tags: javascript, angular

I am identifying the previous url within a component and if the URL is inside an array, I need to update the value of a variable, however when it is changed the value is not updated.

```
this._router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
    e.forEach((page: any, id: any) => {
      this.pages.filter(value => {
        if (_.get(page, 'url', '').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
          this.filterQuery = 'TEST';
        }
      });
    });
});
```

The `filterQuery` value is not reflected in the html.

Comment: Are you using the on push change detection strategy in your component?

Comment: No, how can I do that? It would be very useful in this case, although I did not understand the change.

Comment: Typically this type of problem happens when using the on push strategy. If you aren't using that then it isn't from that.